# Não consigo usar [::1] no docker usando linux

Tags: docker

Estou tentando rodar um container no Docker local usando o endereço: `http://[::1]:31112/`, porém ele não consegue se conectar.

Se eu uso os endereços abaixo, eu consigo fazer o acesso: 
`http://127.0.0.1:31112/` 
`http://0.0.0.0:31112/` 
`http://localhost:31112/`

Sim, eu poderia usar os endereços acima, porém o backend está configurando também pra responder ao endereço `http://[::1]:31112/...`..

Pesquisei bastante pela internet e não achei nada que ajudasse. Eu acredito que seja algo a ver com o `ip6tables`, algo com as portas do ipv6 estar bloqueando as portas.. Tentei bastante coisa e nada até agora.

PS: Já segui a documentação: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/

Comment: o suporte ao ipv6 está habilitado? veja: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/

Comment: Sim, já fiz esses passos.

Comment: Você habilitou o IPV6 no seu sistema? Você consegue acessar outros endereços ipv6? http://ipv6.br/post/habilitando-ipv6-no-linux/

Comment: Sim, o IPV6 está instalado